# Sudden new issue with my app. Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I have a App Script web app that links to a Google Sheet. I also have a custom function that gets all the unique values in a column and joins them with a delimiter. Everything worked perfectly until today when this custom function started throwing the error:

Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (line 22).

Here is the custom function:

```
function getUniqueValues(range) {
  let uniqueValues = [];
  for (let i=0; i<range.length; i++) {
    let cell = range[i][0];
    let tempArray = cell.split(";");
    for (const element of tempArray) {
      let trimmedElement = element.trim();
      if (!uniqueValues.includes(trimmedElement)) {
        uniqueValues.push(trimmedElement);
      }
    }
  }
  let asString = uniqueValues.join("; ")
  return asString;
}
```

Line 22 refers to a different function: `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(MY_ID);`

What's confounding is that the function that actually fetches data from the sheet by ID still works, and the web app itself still works perfectly. Only this custom function used within the sheet does not work anymore.

The code has not changed, I signed all the proper contracts when I deployed it. The only thing that has changed is that I was working on a separate Google Cloud Project today that is not in any way connected with this script. Now all of a sudden it seems Google is treating my web app as a third-party script and not something I own. I tried copying everything over to a new spreadsheet, new app script project, and redoing the deployment/authorizations and I get the same behavior.

I'm not a developer so I was maybe getting in over my head with the Cloud Project APIs and stuff, but I was trying to use the Keep API, and I only linked that with a different script. I have no idea how the two could be connected, but that's the only thing I can think must have caused it.

Thank you

I tried copying everything over to a new spreadsheet and a new app script project, and redoing the deployment/authorizations and I get the same behavior. I also deleted the (ostensibly unrelated) Google Cloud Project and associated App Script project.

Comment: It seems that your showing script has 15 lines. About `Line 22 refers to a different function: const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(MY_ID);`, if you are putting `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(MY_ID);` as a global variable, I think that it is the reason for your current issue. When the custom function is run, first, the global variables are set. I guessed that at that time, such an error occurred. So, please remove the global variable or move them into the function, and test it again. But, I cannot know your actual situation. So, if my guess was not correct, I apologize.

Comment: If my guess was correct, this official document might be useful. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_services

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thank you for your response. My code is about 200 lines long. Line 22 is not declaring a global variable but is also housed within a function. I do not believe there is anything wrong with the code, as it worked perfectly for several weeks. I believe this issue has to do with authorizations, perhaps that I listed myself as the developer for another app. Something is wrong with permissions somewhere in my Google account, but I am at a loss.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `My code is about 200 lines long. Line 22 is not declaring a global variable but is also housed within a function. I do not believe there is anything wrong with the code, as it worked perfectly for several weeks. I believe this issue has to do with authorizations, perhaps that I listed myself as the developer for another app.`, I deeply apologize that my guess from your question was not correct.